# Using RemoteFX without Remote Desktop Services

Tags: remote-desktop

I manage a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 server and I would like to enable RemoteFX for my Windows 7 SP1 client.

As I'm a single user on my server, I don't want to setup optional Remote Desktop Services role. I just use Remote Desktop Connection from Computer's properties.

Is it possible to enable RemoteFX this way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just setup the VM to use the RemoteFX adapter, but you still have to install the RemoteFX components from the remote desktop services role (and of course use W7 Ent/Ult as the VM OS)

However you can then simply RDP direct to the VM's IP.

This brings the licensing issue out - in that because RemoteFX is part of the Remote Desktop Services you still require RDL's to use a RemoteFX enabled VM.